# Android Studio: What does it mean by "M1 Chip not natively supported"?

Tags: android, macos, flutter, android-studio, macos-big-sur

Android Studio is not natively supported for the Apple M1 chip yet. I know it works with Rosetta, but natively not supported.  But what does that mean? Does that mean,

1. The Android Studio IDE is not supported? Or
2. Both IDE and Android SDK not supported?

For someone who install Android Studio just for the sake of Android SDK and use VS Code or some other IDE for the development, how does this affect?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use Android SDK features for Flutter development, run or debug apps on the device, build APK etc.

There is no big difference unless you want to use e.g. Android emulator which requires a bit of setup: https://medium.com/techiepedia/setting-up-android-emulator-in-m1-mac-fff58ec8bff8.

Regarding the Android Studio IDE, you can use it but it still lacks some stuff and has some performance issues. Follow this thread for feedback from other users: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jsq192/android_studio_on_apple_m1_chip/

Comment: Thank you. About the IDE, what sort of things are missing? As a NON ANDROID IDE USER, what will be the impact? (I mean, IDE related stuff or SDK related issues?)

Comment: As I followed on Reddit and other forums some expected shortcuts are either not working as expected or not configurable. The second important thing is performance, some users reported having issues/lags when scrolling through bigger files in Android Studio.

Comment: Okay. IDE related things. Not going to apply for me.